# IDesignTimeDbContextFactory not found on new asp.net .net Core project when trying to initialize db for first time

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm following this get started tutorial with .net core (2.0): 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db

But when I run the command:

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate
```

I get the response:

```
Unable to create an object of type 'MyContext'. Add an implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyContext>' to the project
```

Answer (score 0):

The error basically tells you, that u have no class implementing the IDesignTimeDbContextFactory.

To solve this issue create a class implements the interface, that could look like following:

```
public class Foo : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyContext> {
  //Add interface methods here
}
```

That should solve the issue, because then u have your class Foo which implements this interface, which seems to be necessary.

**Option2**

If that does not help in any case, please check if your class "MyContext" inherits from DbContext.

Your class should look like the following:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext {
//some stuff here
}
```

**Option3**

You may have missed to edit your Startup.cs
The tutorial tells you to add the following into your Startup.cs file in order to register your context

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    var connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;";
    services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
}
```

Comment: The first method moved me onto another error. The interface requires that I have ' public MyContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)' implemented as a method. I am not sure how to implement this: 

   public MyContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            return new MyContext(null);
        }

the options cannot be null. I have triple checked points 2 and 3

Comment: I created another project from scratch and it worked. hmm

Comment: If u find out. what was wrong, post it as your own answer, so others that may face the same issue get an answer :)

Comment: yeah, it was a duplicate - i needed to add something to the main class.